# Why JS doesn't work on a saved page? 

Tags: 7, javascript

I've tried to save /admin/structure/block page and open it with Firefox 14.0.1. After this I cannot drag blocks. Why is that? There are no errors in the console. How should I debug such behavior? I need this to better understand why doesn't Drupal work for JS-loaded content. The symptoms look similar.

Comment: I've found that "Devel" and "Theme Developer" modules often do odd things in the administration area.  do you have either of those modules running?

Comment: are you saying you saved this page to an html file on your local system and then when you open that file it doesn't work?

Comment: jdu, no, I've set up a fresh minimal 7.14 installation for tests. Jimajamma, yes, I've used "full HTML" option. But all the files are available, no 404s

Comment: This is likely related to the XSS filtering that browsers have started adding recently. Check out these links for some more info: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque - http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/06/drupal-and-chrome-refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-wi

Comment: hmm... Doesn't look like this, I don't have this error. Even in Chromium. There are no code that is sent through HTTP POST AFAIU, are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal's jquery.once.js is to blame. Deleting every *-processed class worked.